# neo4j cypher, strange errors when try to update and delete with ID(n)

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am using current version of neo4j, 
I am trying delete or update Node by graph id , when I try to delete passing as parameter for example name, it works normal, but I need delete with id one node with it is relation, and also update node.

```
String remove = "MATCH (n:Player {ID(n): {id} })-[r]-() DELETE n, r";
            ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(remove,
                   params); 

  and

 String query = "MERGE (n:Person {ID(n): {id}}) ON CREATE SET n.name={name}, n.surname={surname}, n.position={position} ON MATCH SET";

            ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query,
                    params);
```

Always I am getting errors like

Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, ':' or '}' (line 1, column 20)
"MERGE (n:Person {ID(n): {id}}) ON CREATE SET n.name={name}, n.surname={surname}, n.position={position} ON MATCH SET"

or

Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, ':' or '}' (line 1, column 20)
"MATCH (n:Player {ID(n): {id} })-[r]-() DELETE n, r"

Usually I am used Spring data neo4j and did not find this type of errors.

Anyone have answers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` is a function that returns the internal id of a node or relationship, but in your query you use it as if it were a property on a node. The way to match a node by its internal id is

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID (n) = {id}
```

In your delete case you could do

```
MATCH (n:Player)-[r]-()
WHERE ID (n) = {id}
DELETE r, n
```

You can't assign the internal id to a node, Neo4j handles that internally, so it doesn't really make sense to use the `ID` function with `MERGE`. You can choose a different uniquely identifying property that you control and for which you create a unique constraint, then use that in most (probably all) places where you now use the internal id.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful, I am trying just delete and update by id using cypher.

Comment: this query update node by id
MATCH (n:Player) WHERE ID (n) = {id} SET  n.name={name}, n.surname={surname}, n.position={position}  RETURN n
Seems I need node id use with where, instead using it as another properties

Comment: You can't use `ID(n)` in the `MATCH` clause: `ID` is a function, and the `MATCH` clause supports only key/value property pairs. Note that the use of key/value pairs in the pattern are only a short-form of using `WHERE` anyway.

Comment: Functions are resolved to values so there is nothing wrong with using `ID` or other functions in the match clause if they are in a value position (`MATCH (n{uid:ID(n)})` and `MATCH (n{name:LOWER("PETER")}` are both valid.) The reason that it's not possible match a node by internal id with only a match clause is that there is no property name for the internal id to use in the node pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Armen,

If you already know the Neo4j id value (the node number), then you can write your first query as

```
START n = node({id}) WITH n MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r
```

However, the more I look at your code, the more I am wondering about your use of id. Do your nodes have a user-defined parameter named **id**? If so, then this all needs to be approached differently.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Hi Jim,
thanks for answer, no I am not defined id, I am trying to use node id as unique field like mysql autoincrement id. May be I will have another unique fields, but I am not want generate another unique id-s .